# SOAP Client with WSDL for R

Tags: r, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to write a code for a SOAP client with R using the SSOAP package. This was my inicial code:

```
wsdl <- getURL("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/webservices/Sistemas/SCW/CDocs/WsDownloadInfs.asmx?WSDL")
def <- processWSDL(doc, verbose = TRUE)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(def = def, verbose = TRUE)
```

But I think the WSDL documentation is too complex (multi-dimensional) for the functions. I tried (this and many other things) to simplify the WSDL choosing just one service, and it helped me with the processWSDL function, but I cannot generate the client functions yet. The error message is:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Please, could somebody help me?

Comment: I'd highly recommend seeing if there is another way to access that data in R. The SOAP R client isn't really actively maintained

Comment: I'm already looking for other ways to access the data... It's an important source and I don't even think in giving up! :)  I've used the package and it worked for another source, but this time maybe it doesn't. As soon as I get the solution I will post here. Thankyou!

Comment: Did you find a way to do this using httr?

Comment: Yes! But now the source changed their environment (for the better).

Answer (score 3):

The RCurl package helps us to do this (see an example on http://www.stat.wvu.edu/~jharner/courses/stat623/docs/RCurlJSS.pdf):

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

###############
#### Login ####
###############

headerfields = c(
Accept = "text/xml",
Accept = "multipart/*",
'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
SOAPAction = "http://www.cvm.gov.br/webservices/Login"
)

body = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<soap:Header>
<sessaoIdHeader xmlns='http://www.cvm.gov.br/webservices/'>
<Guid>8200ac01-bfb5-46d6-a625-38108141fb33</Guid>
<IdSessao>135128883</IdSessao>
</sessaoIdHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<Login xmlns='http://www.cvm.gov.br/webservices/'>
<iNrSist>XXXX</iNrSist>
<strSenha>XXXXX</strSenha>
</Login>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"

reader = basicTextGatherer()

curlPerform(
url = "http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/webservices/Sistemas/SCW/CDocs/WsDownloadInfs.asmx",
httpheader = headerfields,
postfields = body,
writefunction = reader$update
)

xml <- reader$value()
xml
```

You have to do something like this to each one of the fuctions in http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/webservices/Sistemas/SCW/CDocs/WsDownloadInfs.asmx

If you have something easier (or more elegant) and want to share will be welcome!

Tks!